# How to retrieve sharepoint 2013 list data using JQuery or JavaScript and Fill DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to retrieve list data using JavaScript. But something goes wrong. I am trying to debug the code but I am not able to understand that thing.
Following is the JavaScript Code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(PopulateDepartments, "sp.js");
var _ctx = null;
var _web = null;
var _allItems = null;

function PopulateDepartments() {
    debugger;
    _ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    _web = _ctx.get_web();
    var list = _web.get_lists().getByTitle("ServiceType");
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy></Query></View>");
    _allItems = list.getItems(query);
    _ctx.load(_allItems, 'Include(Title,ID)');
    debugger;
    _ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.PopulateDepartmentSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.PopulateDepartmentFaild));
}

function PopulateDepartmentSuccess() {
    var ddlEntry = this.document.getElementById("ddl1");
    ddlEntry.options.length = 0;
    var listEnumerator = _allItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        ddlEntry.options[ddlEntry.options.length] = new Option(currentItem.get_item("Title"), currentItem.get_item("ID"));
    }
}

function PopulateDepartmentFaild() {
    alert("Something went Wrong....!!");
}
```

Whenever I run this code it shows me alert box.
Please Help..

Comment: did you try to use only `<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy>` in your query and set it to the query attribute instead of `set_viewXml` ?

Comment: Hey @user1073122 I tried that one but it is not working. Still it display the alert popup.

Comment: I assumed you fixed the PopulateDepartmentFaild misspelling?

Comment: @Trikks Yes... It was by mistake I put that thing. It in not the main problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are times when this doesn't takes the correct reference.Check if it works with removing this reference .so Instead of this
 _ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.PopulateDepartmentSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.PopulateDepartmentFaild));

try using something like this

_ctx.executeQueryAsync(PopulateDepartmentSuccess,PopulateDepartmentFaild);

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the problem solved by other way.

Answer (score 0):

I think.If your Creating Sharepoint App, it is necessary to give permissions to web in AppManifest.xml.

Comment: Please explain in details. Otherwise, this should be a comment. Not an answer. If you don't have enough repo, wait, have patient, generate repo positively.