# How Retrieve Sharepoint List data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to retrieve list data using Jquery. But I am getting the whole list Html page not the values from the List.
Jquery Code is as follows

```
<script src="../_layouts/15/SharePointProject1/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetAnnouncementData() {
        var soapPacket = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
   <soapenv:Body> \
    <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
     <listName>Temp</listName> \
     <viewFields> \
      <ViewFields> \
        <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
      </ViewFields> \
     </viewFields> \
    </GetListItems> \
   </soapenv:Body> \
  </soapenv:Envelope>";
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://serverName/Lists/Temp/listsView.aspx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapPacket,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    }

    function processResult(xData, status) {
        //jQuery(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
        //    $("<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>").appendTo("#AnnouncementData");
        //});
        //alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
        alert(xData.responseText);
        //alert(status.toString());
        document.getElementById("tarea").value = xData.responseText;
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xData.responseText;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetAnnouncementData();
    });
</script>
```

This code is giving me The list page not list data. I tried to get xml file in div tag so that I can view what it is returning me. It returns me the HTML page of that list.
Please Help.

Comment: You may want to consider using a framework for this, http://camelotjson.codeplex.com/

Comment: Actually I am facing main problem in URL `url: "http://serverName/Lists/Temp/listsView.aspx"`. I think web service fetches data by URL something like `_vti_bin\lists.asmx` but in that I got 404 error.

Comment: So, how does the handler in the listsView.aspx look that receive your post?

Comment: It returns me the whole HTML page(HTML Code) of the ListView page. It contains all the links but the Data it do not display.

Comment: I'd call this a strange approach of retrieving data form SharePoint

Comment: I have done server side code for retrieving data from SharePoint but it slower my system. That's why I am trying to call data by Using JavaScript or JQuery.

Comment: I'd go for either a framework like the json i mentioned or the built-in ClientContext fw. See more here http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.se/2010/07/sharepoint-2010-use-ecmascript-to.html

Comment: Actually Trikks I have also tried that one. If you can check I have posted one question. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888476/how-to-retrieve-sharepoint-2013-list-data-using-jquery-or-javascript-and-fill-dr) Here is the link.

Comment: I Haven't try it yet. I'll try for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check your URL that you have given to access the list.

```
url: "http://serverName/Lists/Temp/listsView.aspx",
```

In this URL if you are accessing the local machine then you have to give localhost in server name.

```
url: "http://localhost:80/Lists/Temp/listsView.aspx",
```

Try using this and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 11):

For me the best option is using REST calls receiving the data as json, is much more cleaner and easier to use.

Also, the good thing is that REST calls on SharePoint are made using Linq, so in this way is more flexible when you create the query, like for example you can do a better pagination, instead of using the crappy paginations of sharepoint that only allow you to do a next items.

```
var ajaxCall = $.getJSON("http://SharePointSiteUrl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName");

ajaxCall.success(function (jsonData) { callbackSuccessFunction(jsonData.d.results); });
ajaxCall.error(function () { callbackErrorFunction({ status: 'error', data: 'error message.' }); });
```

The returned data will be received as json in the following format:

```
{d: {results: [arrays of items]}
```

In case you need to know the name of the list to do the rest call, just call the url:

```
http://SharePointSiteUrl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/
```

Here is some info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that was useful to see the JSON method for hitting Sharepoint!

Answer (score 1):

*An old question, but to help others looking for an answer ...*

The simplest way to "retrieve list data using jQuery" is to use the SharePoint URL protocol. It can return list data in XML and doesn't require you to build SOAP requests. All you need is the list GUID and the ows_ attribute names (use FireBug to inspect the returned XML).

The simple example below will display announcement data. Paste the code into an empty HTML page on your SharePoint site and replace the *siteUrl* and *listId* values with your own.

Microsoft Reference: [URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478653%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

If you need to do more than just read list data then have a look at
[jQuery.SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) by Marc D Anderson.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Tested with WSS3,IE9,FF19 */

$(document).ready( function() {

    var siteUrl = "//london",
        listId  = "{1EC2EC89-B3DC-434D-A63E-AAEBF72E4E89}";

$.get( siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&List=" + listId, 
    function( xml ) {
        var zrow = xml.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
        for(var i=0; i<zrow.length; i++) {
            $("#table1 tbody").append( 
            "<tr><td>"
            + zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Attachments")
            + "</td><td>"
            + zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_LinkTitle") 
            + "</td><td>" 
            + zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Body") 
            + "</td></tr>" 
            );
        }
});
});

</script>

<table id="table1">
<caption>Announcements</caption>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @doitlikejustin - Good point. Using REST calls is an even easier and better method than the URL protocol. The only advantage of the URL protocol is that it works across versions whereas REST works with SP 2010 on. Yes, some of us still work with clients on SP 2007. :(